# ruby: How to remove the string “\n” right before a number from a string?

Tags: ruby, string

I have a Ruby string that looks like:

```
"AUTO TEST\nJANE DOE-RIGHT\n12097105\nJOE BIN\n1216515\nREGRESSION SUE TEST\n10023436"
```

Note that there's no number after `AUTO TEST`. Then I want to turn it into this:

```
"AUTO TEST\nJANE DOE-RIGHT12097105\nJOE BIN1216515\nREGRESSION SUE TEST10023436"
```

Remove `\n` only it's standing right before a number.
The result can be an array or another string.

Anyone can help me with this please?

Comment: The data seems to be somehow structured via newlines – why do you want to remove those newlines instead of e.g. group adjacent name / number pairs?

Comment: I'm modifying the old code for automation test, for the new update UI on the web, it should group name/number pair for validating after that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try replacing `\n(?=\d)` with empty string:

```rb
input = "AUTO TEST\nJANE DOE-RIGHT\n12097105\nJOE BIN\n1216515\nREGRESSION SUE TEST\n10023436"
output = input.gsub(/\n(?=\d)/, '')
puts output
```

This prints:

```
AUTO TEST
JANE DOE-RIGHT12097105
JOE BIN1216515
REGRESSION SUE TEST10023436
```

Comment: Thank so much bro! it works properly on my code.